# Does dapr support Cross kubernetes cluster service discovery?

Tags: kubernetes, service-discovery, dapr

I know dapr has support for service discovery built in but how does that work when deployed to kubernetes in a cross cluster setup?  Can't seem to find example or docs.

Comment: `dapr` will use the out-of-the-box `k8s` DNS. If a service / component can be resolved within your cluster then `dapr` will be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Dapr is not designed for that use case. It might be better to use something like https://skupper.io/ to create cross-cluster flat network and then use Dapr on top.
This a valid scenario presented by a user in July community call

Comment: Any examples showing how this could be setup?